# wpf webbrowser uri containing other language such as Korean

Tags: c#, wpf, uri

i have a trouble when i use `MyWebBrowser.Source = new Uri(`**uri**`);`

i want to add Korean to **uri**. but when i do it, i can see broken characters which was from Korean. i searched for solution, but i couldn't understand the way. someone instructs the way using encode/decode.. but, i don't know how to apply it to my code.

please help me
.

`<Grid Background="White"><WebBrowser Name="MyWebBrowser" /></Grid>`

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        change_room();
    }
    private void change_room()
    {
        string room_name = "example";

        string nick = "한글";// 한글 means Korean.

        string uri = "http://" + room_name + ".com/chat?nick=" + nick ;

        try
        {
            MyWebBrowser.Source = new Uri(uri);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

`string uri = "http://" + room_name + ".server.ohcs.uu.gl/chat?nick=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(nick,`**System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("euc-kr")**`` `) + "&text=&sessid=" + room_name; ``
above code can't make Korean correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i add more explanations about solution i found.

---

this is xaml code   <.WebBrowser x:Name="webBrowser" /.>

below is cs code

public room1()

{

string nick = "한글";

webBrowser.Navigate("http:/freechat.esy.es/minichat?chat=room1&nick=" + nick );

}

---

### above codes are inappropriate because "한글" is not a regular letter i think.

UriBuilder builder = new UriBuilder("http://freechat.esy.es/minichat?chat=room1&nick=한글");

string url = builder.ToString();

WebBrowser web = new WebBrowser();
web.Navigate(url);

**UriBuilder** convert unregualr letters containing "한글"[string url] to regualr letters which can be accepted to web.

input letters : [http://freechat.esy.es/minichat?chat=room1&nick=**한글**]

translated letters by UriBuilder :

[http:/freechat.esy.es/minichat?chat=room1&nick=**%ED%95%9C%EA%B8%80**]

---

I found the answer.  I'm currently using the following code and it now works fine.

```
    string make_uri(string uri)
    {
        UriBuilder ub = new UriBuilder(uri);
        string ubS = ub.ToString();
        return ubS;
    }

    string send_uri { get; set; }

    private void NavigateTo()
    {
        int cs = combo1.SelectedIndex;

        if (DN == "Your Nick")
        {
            if (cs == 0) send_uri = ("http://freechat.esy.es/minichat?chat=room1" + mode + key);
            else if (cs == 1) send_uri = ("http://freechat.esy.es/minichat?chat=chataa" + mode + key);
            else if (cs == 2) send_uri = ("http://freechat.esy.es/minichat?chat=room2" + mode + key);
        }
        else
        {
            if (cs == 0) send_uri = (make_uri("http://freechat.esy.es/minichat?chat=room1&nick=" + DN + mode + key));
            else if (cs == 1) send_uri = (make_uri("http://freechat.esy.es/minichat?chat=chataa&nick=" + DN + mode + key));
            else if (cs == 2) send_uri = (make_uri("http://freechat.esy.es/minichat?chat=room2&nick=" + DN + mode + key));
        }

        webBrowser.Navigate(send_uri);
    }
```

Comment: Can you explain what it is about your solution that fixes your original problem?  This might help future readers of the question.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `HttpUtility.UrlEncode` method on strings that are from user input and strings that contain characters that'd break the URL/not get through correctly (ampersand, foreign chars, etc). This way, it'll be safe for use in a URL.

```
string uri = "http://" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(room_name) + ".com/chat?nick=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(nick, System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("euc-kr"));
```

The [`HttpUtility`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class can be found in the assembly `System.Web.dll`. If there's an error relating to the namespace not being found, make sure to add the reference to `System.Web.dll` using the `Add References` dialog.

Comment: sorry..                                                         string uri = "http://" + room_name + ".server.ohcs.uu.gl/chat?nick=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(nick,System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("euc-kr")`) + "&text=&sessid=" + room_name; above code can't make Korean correct.

Comment: It should work if I recall correctly, but I'll edit my answer just in case.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It work but, when i send encoded string to chatserver, it doesn't work. it maybe due to another reason..anyway, Thanks!! I gave up to make this code correct..